# selectedRowInComponent crashes in numberOfRowsInComponent

Tags: xcode4, uipickerview

I have 2 components in a pickerView created programmatically using Xcode (4.4.1)

```
UIPickerView *picker = [[[UIPickerView alloc] init] retain];
[picker sizeToFit];
picker.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
picker.delegate = self;
picker.dataSource = self;
picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
```

I think no need to dump all the code related to this pickerView, since I know where it crashed.

The pickerView works like a charm in the simulator, but as soon as I tested it in the iPhone device (5.1.1) it crashed in the following method:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
  if (component == 0) return [array1 count];
  if (component == 1) {
    NSLog(@"selectedRowInComponent:%i",[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]); //CRASHES HERE
    return [[array2 objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]] count];
  }
}
```

It thoughed the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

As I said, if tested in simulator (NO PROBLEM), if tested in device (CRASHES)!!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it crashes on the line you indicated and not the line after it?

A difference between the simulator and real devices that frequently trips people up is that the file system is case-sensitive on real devices, but not in the simulator.  This could be causing your problem if you are loading the data for the picker from a file, and you have specified the case incorrectly.  I've seen people make that mistake several times.  Look at `array2` and ensure it contains what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

having same issue... does crash on ios8 only.
strangely I got this issue when i reverted the components. (invert 0 and 1)

replace [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1] with a property holding current selected row, as there is a concurrency issue